# How can I make my 2nd tier navigation appear on hover?

Tags: html, css, navigation, hover

I have a navigation bar including my Home, Menu and Photogallery. In the actual, physical menu, I have 5 pages consisting of different menu items, and I'd like to have a dropdown consist of all of those pages when I hover over **Menu**. `display: block;` will not operate when I hover over the Menu button. Any solutions to this?

My HTML:

```
<nav> <!-- Navigation -->
    <hr>
    <a href="Big Duck.html">Home</a>        
    <a class="MenuDropdown">Menu</a>
    <a href="Photogallery.html">Photogallery</a>

        <div class="DropdownButtons"> <!-- Dropdown navigation -->
            <a href="MulticourseMeals">Multicourse Meals</a>
            <a href="Appetizers">Appetizers</a>
            <a href="Soups">Soups</a>
            <a href="Entrees">Entrees</a>
            <a href="SidePlates">Side Plates</a>
            <a href="Desserts">Desserts</a>
        </div>

</nav>
```

My CSS:

```
.DropdownButtons {
    display: none; /* To hide the five page button menu */

    text-align: center;
    width: 100vw;

    margin: 0px;
    padding: .2% 0% .2% 0%;

    transition: 0.3s;

    position: fixed;
    top: 5.7%;
    background-color: hsla(9 , 57%, 60%, 1);
}

.DropdownButtons a {
    font-family: 'Didact Gothic', sans-serif;
    font-size: 170%;
    color: hsla(48, 70%, 63%, 1);
    text-decoration: none;

    margin: 0% .5% 0% .5%;
    padding: .2% .5% .2% .5%;

    transition: 0.3s;
}

.MenuDropdown:hover .DropdownButtons {
    display: block; /* To show the 5 page button menu */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the current css selection you're using is assuming the menu is a child of the link. What you're looking for is the general sibling selector

```
.MenuDropdown:hover ~ .DropdownButtons
```

You should also apply the css rule to `.DropdownButtons:hover` so the menu stays open for the user. Below is a working snippet

```css
.DropdownButtons {
    display: none; /* To hide the five page button menu */

    text-align: center;
    width: 100vw;

    margin: 0px;
    padding: .2% 0% .2% 0%;

    transition: 0.3s;

    position: fixed;
    top: 5.7%;
    background-color: hsla(9 , 57%, 60%, 1);
}

.DropdownButtons a {
    font-family: 'Didact Gothic', sans-serif;
    font-size: 170%;
    color: hsla(48, 70%, 63%, 1);
    text-decoration: none;

    margin: 0% .5% 0% .5%;
    padding: .2% .5% .2% .5%;

    transition: 0.3s;
}

.MenuDropdown:hover ~ .DropdownButtons, .DropdownButtons:hover  {
    display: block; /* To show the 5 page button menu */
}
```

```html
<nav> <!-- Navigation -->
    <hr>
    <a href="Big Duck.html">Home</a>        
    <a class="MenuDropdown">Menu</a>
    <a href="Photogallery.html">Photogallery</a>

        <div class="DropdownButtons"> <!-- Dropdown navigation -->
            <a href="MulticourseMeals">Multicourse Meals</a>
            <a href="Appetizers">Appetizers</a>
            <a href="Soups">Soups</a>
            <a href="Entrees">Entrees</a>
            <a href="SidePlates">Side Plates</a>
            <a href="Desserts">Desserts</a>
        </div>

</nav>
```

Comment: Yep! This works, thanks much! One error I have though is the transition code isn't working for how long it appears/disappears. Any fixes to that?

Comment: You can't animate display none and block. You'd need some js to force a reflow. 
here is an article that covers that. https://matheusazzi.com/animating-from-display-none-with-css-and-callbacks/#:~:targetText=There's%20a%20technique%20you%20can,a%20reflow%20on%20that%20element.

Answer (score 1):

To do this effect you just need to have a div inside another with **display: none**; This way the second div will stay hidden. Then you can select this div when the parent is under the mouse using **div:hover div** and set it to show using **display: block**.

Usually you can mark your menu-items using a unordered list. I made a menu-bar for you using flex layout:

HTML:

```
<nav id="navigator">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="Big Duck.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="MenuDropdown">Menu</a></li>
    <li>
      <a>Dropdown</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="Drop">Home 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="Down">Menu 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
#navigator ul {
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#navigator li {
  display: flex-item;
}
#navigator a {
  padding: 20px 20px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
#navigator a:hover {
  background-color: tomato;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#navigator ul ul {
  display: none; /*hide the dropdown here...*/
  position: absolute;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#navigator li:hover ul {
  display: flex; /*and show it here!*/
}
```

[image]

You can see this code here: https://jsfiddle.net/x93ojma8/